# Zend won't show project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have Windows 7, Apache 2_4, PHP5, and Zend Framework 1.12.9. I created a new project (called "thenextsocial") using "zf create project" command. All of the folders were created correctly. But when I try to go to httpd://thenextsocial.local in my web browser, instead of seeing the project main page, I get a page titled "index of /" that only says "Index of / . index.php"

I followed the steps outlined at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/zend-framework-from-scratch--net-22502 to install, set up, and try to use zend.

I have checked, double checked, and triple checked, and can't find anything set up incorrectly. I have looked all over Stack Overflow for an answer. The answers to everyone else's questions about problems similar to mine haven't helped at all. Those answers have only made me check my httpd.conf file, localhost settings, php.ini file,  and environment variables about 150 times each.

Help please.

Comment: Is your project in your document root or not?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the apache setup or htaccess file.

Comment: My project IS in the document root @IndrasinhBihola It's in the document root in the virtual host I set up for the project in the apache httpd.conf file. That's one of the things I checked repeatedly to make sure I had the document root set to the correct location. The virtual host is set up as:                                      <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thenextsocial.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/thenextsocial/public/"
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/thenextsocial/public/">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C:/Apache24/htdocs is your default DocumentRoot for *:80 virtual host and it has AllowOverride set to all, are you able to open http://localhost/thenextsocial/public . If not, you need to add .htaccess in public folder according to ZF1 specification, else you need to add AllowOverride all to VirtualHost in httpd.conf or whatever file

Answer (score 0):

About to show how much over my head I am, but I found my answer. I thought PHP was working, because I created a simple "Hello World" PHP file and it worked... or seemed to work. I went back through everything and noticed that I could see the closing php tag "?>" when I ran it. That's because it was displaying as HTML. I had left the letter "d" out of "PHPIniDir "C:/php" so PHP wasn't even working. Now on to my next problem which I'll pose as a different question later. I can't get PHP to parse automatically in my virtual hosts if the php file doesn't have closing tags. I have to turn on the php_admin_flag in every virtual host I set up. Ugh! This is hindering me with Zend.